# Transfer from RAID-1 to RAID-0 -- easy as cloning?

Tags: windows, raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, raid1

I have a RAID-1 of 1TB drives using on-board RAID. I have 2 new 240GB SSDs I want to place in RAID-0. This is Windows Server 2012.

I know with disk cloning/transferring that it is important going from small to bigger sized disks. Do I need to drop all my free space to it's own partition then copy/clone the partition with the contents on it?

Can I just use cloning software to clone from the RAID-1 to RAID-0?

Yes, I understand RAID-0 is not ideal or safe. I just would like to the performance gain and I keep backups on several NAS devices and other locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cloning software operates at a filesystem level, then yes it is just that easy. You could also use some sort of dircopy type program (I'm more familiar with linux, myself) - basically, anything that simply copies recursively from the old RAID-1 to the new RAID-0 will work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer on this one is, "it depends". It depends on the software doing the restore back to the new array. Some software has the option to allow restore to a smaller partition, such as [Acronis](https://kb.acronis.com/content/2770). Some automatically will fail if the source partition is greater than the new destination, even if the actual used space is well within the limits of the new destination.

Run a defrag beforehand to attempt to cleanup the partition as much as possible.